# docker build hangs on when trying to activate inside a react dir

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

[my Dockerfile code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR60S.png)

im trying to run build command inside a react dir - "frontend"

when i use the command "docker build . "
the cursor move a line down but nothing else happens.

the same file and commands works fine outside the react dir.

Comment: You seem to have provided a link to a PNG file instead of your actual Dockerfile and other information needed to reproduce the issue.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] -- the Dockerfile and any other source code required to reproduce the problem -- as text and not images, in the question and not behind links?

Comment: It seems that you are using windows, sometime the docker context takes time being passed onto the docker (that might run linux vm on your windows) so, I'd try waiting some time.

In addition make sure to have a dockerignore file that it won't copy the node_modules folder.